# Writing python two-level loop comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have an input file that contains lines of:

```
key \t  value1  \t value2 .....
```

I'd like read this file into a dictionary where key is the first token of the line and the value is the list of the values.

I think something like this would do it, but python gives me an error that name `l` is not defined. How do I write a comprehension that has two levels of "for" statements like this?

```
f = open("input.txt")
datamap = {tokens[0]:tokens[1:] for tokens in l.split("\t") for l in enumerate(f)}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the csv reader module to do this work instead of splitting it manually yourself. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. Also look at the dictreader function https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: Use the same order as for nested loops: `{... for l in enumerate(f) for tokens in l.split("\t")}`. The expression can be imagined as the body of the innermost loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `csv` module and insert each row into a dictionary:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt') as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
    datamap = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in reader}
```

This sidesteps the issue altogether.

You *can* put a `str.split()` result into a tuple to create a 'loop variable':

```
datamap = {row[0]: row[1:] for l in f for row in (l.strip().split("\t"),)}
```

Here `row` is bound to the one `str.split()` result from the tuple, effectively creating a `row = l.strip().split('\t')` 'assignment'.

Answer (score 2):

[Martijn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997535/789671) got you covered for improving the process, but just to directly address the issues you were seeing with your code:

First, `enumerate` is not doing what you think it's doing (although I'm not entirely sure what you think it's doing). You can just get rid of it.

Second, Python is trying to resolve this:

```
tokens[0]:tokens[1:] for tokens in l.split("\t")
```

*before* it sees what you're defining `l` as. You can put parentheses around the second comprehension to make it evaluate as you intended:

```
datamap = {tokens[0]:tokens[1:] for tokens in (l.split("\t") for l in f)}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was exactly curious about this. :)